# How can I resolve "Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined"? (Google MAPS API)

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, undefined, uncaught-exception

I have a project which consist in displaying a google map with informations related to the city places (points of interests, such as school, restaurant, subway, ...)
But I've to learn to use the API first.

I've difficulties to display a simple marker, indeed I have "Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined" in Chrome console and marker doesn't appear. I searched everywhere in the forum but nothing helped me.

I provide you my little HTML code :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
 <p> TEST MAP </p>
<div id="map" style="height: 500px; width:900px;"></div>



<script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>

<script async defer  src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_KEY&callback=initMap"></script> 

<!-- Si le script n'est pas lu par le navigateur -->
<noscript>
    <p>Attention : </p>
    <p>Afin de pouvoir utiliser Google Maps, JavaScript doit être activé.</p>
    <p>Or, il semble que JavaScript est désactivé ou qu'il ne soit pas supporté par votre navigateur.</p>
    <p>Pour afficher Google Maps, activez JavaScript en modifiant les options de votre navigateur, puis essayez à nouveau.</p>
</noscript>

</body>
</html>
```

Then, this is my Javascript code :

```
    var maCarte;

    function initMap() {
        var optionsCarte = {
        center: {lat: 43.4810896, lng: -1.540436},
        zoom: 16
      }
      maCarte = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),optionsCarte);
    }

    // Création d'un marqueur sur la carte : Ne fonctionne pas
    var optionsMarqueur = {
                        position: {lat: 43.4810896, lng: -1.540436}, 
                        map: maCarte
                    };

    var marqueur = new google.maps.Marker(optionsMarqueur);
```

Comment: Move your script include so that it's after the google script include.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google maps is loaded `asynchronously` - even when you include the script tag directly. So don't use any `google.maps` classes (like `google.maps.Marker`) until inside your callback (which you have specified to be `initMap`).

Modify `test.js` so your marker is created inside your `initMap` callback.

You were also using `maCarte` while it was still `undefined`. So you need to add your marker to the map (`maCarte`) only **after** you have created it:

```
    var maCarte;
    var marqueur

function initMap() {

    var optionsCarte = {
        center: {lat: 43.4810896, lng: -1.540436},
        zoom: 16
    }

    maCarte = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),optionsCarte);

    // Création d'un marqueur sur la carte : Ne fonctionne pas
    var optionsMarqueur = {
        position: {lat: 43.4810896, lng: -1.540436}, 
        map: maCarte
    };

    marqueur = new google.maps.Marker(optionsMarqueur); 
}
```

Then, it doesn't matter if you include `test.js` before or after your google maps script tag.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works ! 
I spend my day on this :/ 
I believe there is a long way to go before I become a pro of Google Maps ^^

Comment: Thank you sir; I have the same error with a totally different setup but after seeing your solution I went looking to matchup the callback function to the function name that instantiates the Google Map object and sure enough, they were different.

Answer (score 1):

You need to load googleapis before you load your test code.

edit: Can you move these to the head as well?

```
<script defer  src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_KEY&callback=initMap"></script> 
<script defer type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
```

Async and defer do two different things, you shouldn't put them in the same script tag.

async downloads the file during HTML parsing and will pause the HTML parser to execute it when it has finished downloading.

defer downloads the file during HTML parsing and will only execute it after the parser has completed.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response :)
I tried what you said but it doesn't work

Comment: Did you add defer to the test.js script and remove async from the googleapis script? You don't need to do async AND defer on the same script tag, they do different things.

Comment: If I do that it says "initMap()" is not a function and I have a blank page

Answer (score 0):

You use asyn and defer attribute:

- async: load asynchronous script
- defer: excute at the end

but your test.js is load and exec synchrnous: before google maps sdk
consequently google is not defined

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_async.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_defer.asp

Comment: Thanks for your quick response :)
If I understand well, I have just to move my first script after the second. 
But it doesn't work, I have the same message in the console and marker doesn't appear

Comment: move after and add async and defer into your script tag

Comment: Like this ?

        <script async defer src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_KEYcallback=initMap"></script> 
        <script async defer type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>